# Android How to pass EditText and ImageView within Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So what i want to do is that from  first.java Fragment pass the EditText data and ImageView to two.java. I manage to replace first.java with two.java when i click the button (transaction.replace(R.id.top,Two);). I am familiar with Intent but i am not sure how to pass EditText and Imageview in Fragments. Please refer to the screenshot.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        first first=new first();
        transaction.add(R.id.top,first);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**first.java**

```
public class first extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

Button get_button;
EditText get_input_name;
ImageView get_image;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);

    get_input_name=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    get_button=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
    get_image=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.img1); 
    get_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

public void onClick(View v){

    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    two Two=new two();
    transaction.replace(R.id.top,Two);
    transaction.commit();

}

}
```

**two.java**

```
public class two extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
}

}
```

[image]

Anyone can help? thx

Comment: Use Bundle to pass Both.

Comment: You should name your classes in **Camel Case** manner.

Comment: Thx guys. will do that in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both values in `Bundle`.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edtValue", <EditText value>);
bundle.putString("image", <Image path/url>);
```

Pass `Bundle` in `Fragment`

```
Two.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fetch these value in second fragment

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String edtValue = bundle.getString("edtValue");
```

**Tip :** You should use camel case while declaring class name, check [Java Coding Style Guidelines](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html) or [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: Its valid if its hosted by the same activity

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy from OP's question its clearly visible that both fragments are hosted by single activity only, OP is moving from fragment to fragment not activity to fragment

Comment: yes , you are right but my was incase of hosted on different activites

Comment: @RRR thx for ur info. can you edit ur post to tell me exactly where to place the coding? As I have uploaded all the coding in my questions so that it will be easier for me to understand. thx

Comment: from first fragment pass values in `Bundle`, and in second fragment fetch those values. I can not give you full code, sorry for that as i am against Spoon-Feeding. I can give you a way to achieve that but not full code.

Comment: @RRR well , i understand where to place the code. but it has syntax error. Because it's my first time doing that. Thats why i need help in this example.

Comment: syntax error for what? for which line and what have you written that cause error?

Comment: @maybe u tell me for this part instead?   my editText id is   input_name and the Imageview id is img1  .bundle.putString("edtValue", <EditText value>);

Comment: `bundle.putString("edtValue",input_name.getText().toString());` and same for your `ImageView` if you are using image from drawable put that path, if it is from url put that string, if its from sdcard put image path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117601/discussion-between-gosulove-and-rrr).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share data between two fragments if they are on different activities but you can declare a variable in activity and get the result in any of the two fragments.
If both fragment are on same activity you can use Bundle , putExtra method for sharing data.
Further read [Link](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-fragment-how-to-pass-data-between-fragments-in-an-activity/)

RRR answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("your_data",value);    
two Two=new two();
two.setArguments(args);
transaction.replace(R.id.top,Two);
transaction.commit();
```

in two.java
Get these value and set in fragment

```
public class two extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    String s = b.getInt("your_data");
    // Do Whatever you want

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: i got error for this args.putInt("your data",value);

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using constructor too.

in second activity make on constructor with values you want to get.

```
String text; 
String imagepath; 
// or int imageid;

public Two(String text, String imagepath /* or int imageid*/) {
    super();
    this.text = text;
    this.imagepath = imagepath;

    //or
    this.imageid = imageid;
}
```

and from first fragment do like this.

```
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
two Two=new two(get_input_name.getText().toString.Trim(),imagepath /*or R.drawable.Imageid*/);
transaction.replace(R.id.top,Two);
transaction.commit();
```